# Make pytest include functional tests in its count

Tags: python, functional-testing, pytest

I'm starting a new project and trying to follow strict Test-Driven Development. I have a basic setup in place and working and am using [pytest](http://pytest.org/latest/) to run tests.

Tests are discovered and run correctly. They fail when they should and pass when they should. But in pytest's results, the number of tests performed is zero. This isn't a big deal, but I would *like* the visual feedback that confirms the test file is being run.

Failing:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
    ...
collected 0 items / 1 errors

=================================== ERRORS ====================================
___________ ERROR collecting tests/functional_tests/test_package.py ___________
    ...
=========================== 1 error in 0.05 seconds ===========================
```

Passing:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
    ...
collected 0 items

======================== no tests ran in 0.03 seconds =========================
```

---

For the record, my first functional test is just `import`ing the package.

```
# Can we import the package?
import packagename

assert packagename is not None
```

The slightly redundant `assert` was my attempt at getting pytest to count this as "a test", since I know it rewrites `assert` to be more informative.

The test is run correctly, but the test session doesn't count this as being a test. I don't much care *how* it counts the tests (the whole file is one, each `assert` is one, whatever), but I would like it to do so!

Answer (score 1):

### Put it in a function.

Okay, after playing around some more, I may have solved my own problem. This, for instance, works (the whole function gets counted as one test).

```
def test_import():
    # Can we import the package?
    import packagename
```

I'll leave the question open to see if anyone has a better answer.